# How to use DotNetOpenAuth in my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, dotnetopenauth

I have been trying to implement login structure like the one used by stack overflow in asp.net. I have read many blogs and previous questions, from which I found out that it uses open id .After researching on that i came across the  [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/). I read the blog by [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/17/Integrating-OpenID-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application-using-DotNetOpenAuth) .I have downloaded the zip file from DotNetOpenAuth.From all this I have understood, what I have to do but I could not understand how to do it. How to integrate DotNetOpenAuth in my project, which files to use from the whole bundle. A step By step guide to start integration is what I need. Or a complete documentation of how to use DotNetOpenAuth.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx) is a nice one but it is for MV3

Comment: The DotNetOpenAuth has its own documentation. Didn't it help you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.
What i needed i found it [here](http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx)
Hope this helps to someone else

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful - [Step by Step Twitter OpenId with DotnetOpenAuth](http://dheemhi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/step-by-step-twitter-with.html)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problems as you. Though I found something that can help us figure things out, so I am sharing it with you since I had a hard time finding examples. I hope this helps !

http://pastebin.com/gpRqaQnG

Lewis

Comment: You really should just post the code within your answer.  This is because when pastebin.com goes down your answer will still exist.